# Simple server in c does not work

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, server

I coded this little server and it doesn't work. The message directly at the beginning isn't printed out as  well and I don't know how to analyse the problem by using gdb. Could you help me? Is there any library missing or whats wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 7890

int main(void) {
    printf("HelloWorld");
    int sockfd, sock_client;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("Could no open socket\n");
    }
    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof (int)) == -1) {
        printf("Coud not reuse\n");
    }

    printf("socket was created");


    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_host, sockaddr_client;
    sockaddr_host.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_host.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    sockaddr_host.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
    memset(&(sockaddr_host.sin_zero), '\0', 8);



    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr_host, sizeof (sockaddr_host)) == -1) {
        printf("Could not bind socket");
    }
    if (listen(sockfd, 1) == -1) {
        printf("Could not start listening");

    } else {
        printf("Server is listening on %s: %d", inet_ntoa(sockaddr_host.sin_addr), ntohs(sockaddr_host.sin_port));
    }

    while (1) {
        socklen_t client_length = sizeof (sockaddr_client);
        if ((sock_client = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sockaddr_client, &client_length)) == -1) {
            printf("Could not accept connection");
        }
        printf("sever: got connection from %s on port %d", inet_ntoa(sockaddr_client.sin_addr), ntohs(sockaddr_client.sin_port));
        char message[] = "Hello\n";
        if (send(sockfd, message, sizeof (message), 0) == -1) {
            printf("Could not send message");
        }
        close(sock_client);
        close(sockfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean the "HelloWorld" is not printed? please be more specific and explain, what your output actually is, and what you did expect.

Comment: if( question.contains( "It doesn't work" ) ) { close( question, reason = "Unclear what you are asking." ) }

Answer (score 1):

If you were missing a library, the linker would already complain.

Standard output is usually line buffered. Add a newline after `HelloWorld` and you will see at least the first output.

```
printf("HelloWorld\n");
```

Same with the other `printf`.

---

After adding `\n` to each `printf`, you will see

> HelloWorld
>   socket was created
>   Server is listening on 0.0.0.0: 7890

When you now connect to your server, e.g. with [`netcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc)

```
nc localhost 7890
```

your server will output

> sever: got connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 36496

---

Some errors remain though.

```
if(send(sockfd, message, sizeof(message), 0) == -1) {
```

should be rather

```
if(send(sock_client, message, sizeof(message) - 1, 0) == -1) {
```

Otherwise the server sends the message to itself. Also `sizeof(message)` includes the final `\0`.

Finally, you shouldn't `close(sockfd);`, if you want to continue receiving further connection requests beyond the first one.

Comment: This should really be a comment, no?

Comment: Patience you must have my young padawan, SCNR ;-)

Comment: Red light camera says "Gaming the system you are"

Comment: Touché! ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> The message directly at the beginning isn't printed out as well

After the `printf` add `fflush` as

```
printf("HelloWorld");
fflush(stdout);
```

> Is there any library missing

I don't thinks so any library is missing because you have successfully compiled the program and created the executable.